# Paste last update of textarea content on jqgrid using jquery

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I have a textarea and a grid using jqgrid. I'm trying to display textarea content on this grid but I got a problem, when I tried to copy a text from excel and paste it on textarea for the first time, I can display this text on grid, but when I paste other text for the second time I have a concatenation of texts. How Can I display the last update text on grid?. I hope my issue was clear. Thank you

Here is a snippet of code:

```js
$("#textareaid").bind("paste", function(e)
{
setTimeout(function()
{
   pastedData = $("#textareaid").val();
   console.log(pastedData);
   rows = pastedData.split(/\r?\n/);
            
   for (var i = 0; i < rows.length-1; i++) 
   {
                      
      var cells = rows[i].split('\t');

      mydata.push({
                        
            X: cells[0],
            Y: cells[1]
      });
                    
   }
     console.log(mydata);
                    grid.jqGrid('addRowData',i+1,mydata);
             
        });
     
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your array **mydata** is global and every time you paste a string, the data is added to the array and this array is inserted into the jqGrid. In order to to overcome this you will need to reset the array before or after adding the new pasted data to the grid